# AsyncAction execute two times in onDateset in android

Tags: android

I want to call AsyncAction when date is set.

My target is when date is set Async is run but It run two times now.

I wrote below code but Async execute two times.

```
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {

           String mo = null,dmo = null;
           int month = monthOfYear+1;
           if(month<=9)
           {
               mo = "0"+ String.valueOf(month);
           }
           //int dmonth = monthOfYear+1;
           if(dayOfMonth<=9)
           {
               dmo = "0"+ String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);
           }


            new AsyncActionBalance().execute("LAST."+String.valueOf(mo.toString()+dmo.toString()), "RECHARGE REPORT", null);


        }

};
```

**for call**

```
DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(report.this, date, myCalendar
                        .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

dpd.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Its is an android bug. It is happening from Jelly Bean
[See the bug reported in android](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34833)

To overcome this issue. Don't call onDateSet listener instead set positive button. Try out like this to get date from date picker

```
 final DatePickerDialog dpDialog = new DatePickerDialog(activity, null, year, month, dayOfMonth);
        dpDialog.setButton(DatePickerDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                android.widget.DatePicker dp = dpDialog.getDatePicker();
                Log.e(TAG, "selected Date:" + dp.getYear() + " " + dp.getMonth() + "  " + dp.getDayOfMonth());
            }
        });

        dpDialog.show();
```

Comment: I solved that using counter. Now I also put BUTTON_NEGATIVE and I called dialog.dismiss(); after that also execute run. why ??